# Create email message body from form values

Tags: xml, email, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

In Livecycle Designer ES2, is it possible to edit the XML of the Submit button to take data from the filled form and put it into the message body of the email? As an example, if I had the following field / values:

```
firstName / John
lastName / Smith
DOB / 1/1/72
email / johnsmith@gmail.com
```

The message body of the email would look like this:

Name: John Smith
DOB: 1/1/72
Email Address: johnsmith@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send email you can use *app.mailMsg()* function from AcroForms specification. 
Add a standard button to your form and add the following code to its *click* event:

```
//Email adressee
var cToAddr = "fillproperEmail@example.com";

//Subject
var cSubLine = "Put proper subject here";

//Body
var cBody = "Name: "+firstName.rawValue+" "+lastName.rawValue+" DOB: "+DOB.rawValue+" Email Address: "+email.rawValue;

// Send an email
event.target.app.mailMsg({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});
```

Detailes about *app.mailMsg()* function and similar ones you can find here: http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/dynamically-setting-submit-e-mail-address